# Do I need C# to create a dll to be used in IronPython?

Tags: c#, dll, ironpython

I'd like to call C# functions **from** IronPython. I've read some topics about it, and it seems to follow these steps:

1. Create a dll from the C# functions
2. Use clr.AddReference
3. Use your function from IronPython

My noob question is: do I need to have my source code in C# in order to create the dll? Or is C++ ok? Why?

Thanks a lot,
Arnaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any .NET-based language can be used to generate the DLL, which you can use in your IronPython code.